# list all xml files within a directory and subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash

I want to list all .xml files in a dir and its subdir. I tried ls -LR but not able to filter out other files apart from .xml..

I want something like ls -LR | grep *.xml .

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `find` command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.xml'
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks .. it works. I would like to add another condition though.. I want it to find in all subfolders except one folder.. can this be done?

Comment: quick an dirty `... | grep -v not_that_dir`

Comment: @user1164061 There are huge options of `find` command. Search google with `linux find exclude dir` will give you some tips.

Comment: @user1164061: `find  \( -wholename ./not/this/dir -prune \) -o -type f -name '*.xml' -print`

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question with bash:

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
ls !(exclude.this.dir)/**/*.xml
```

Comment: You should note that globstar is a bash v4 feature